# change the html of div tag using jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

hi i am new at codeigniter.
i want to change my div tag using jquery ajax.

Comment: Could you add just a *few* more details? Like what you want to add, where you get it from and where you want it to go? NB that an introduction to jQuery (e.g. http://jqfundamentals.com/book/book.html) may be useful for you at this point...

Comment: ok  lonesomeday i want to make a poll in my website. i make my controller, model and view in codeigniter. now i get the poll in my view.when user will vote on that poll the data is also stored in database. afterb that i want to change the poll status means i want to add that vote.

Comment: here is my code function submitVote(frmName){
 
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",  
    url: "<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/community/community/add_vote/?",
  data: "vote="+the_value+"&poll="+poll,  
    success: function(msg){
   alert(msg);    
    }
  });
}

Comment: two general points: 1) if you're responding to a particular person then prefixing their name with the `@` symbol (so '@lonesomeday' rather than 'lonesomeday') will notify that person that a response exists/has been made. 2) if you're adding information to support/expand/refine/improve your question, you should really **add it to the question**, by clicking the 'edit' link below the tags. This is just a heads-up, not a criticism =) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @David Thomas ok i will take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment your current code seems to be like this -

```
function submitVote(frmName){ 
  $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/community/community/add_vote/?",
   data: "vote="+the_value+"&poll="+poll,
   success: function(msg){ 
    alert(msg);
   }
 }); 
}
```

First thing i would like to add is from where are you getting the `the_value` and poll values`enter code here` ? Because you have mentioned nowhere regarding this in your code.
secondly there is no need to send `?` in your url. Also the parameter `frmName` which you are taking in function is used nowhere.

Your code can be modified to work properly as follows -

```
function submitVote(frmName){ 
      $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'text',
       url: "<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/community/community/add_vote/",
       data: "vote="+the_value+"&poll="+poll,
       success: function(msg){ 
        //i am assuming that from controller in msg you are sending the total number of votes to that particular entity after ending current vote.
        $('#div id where you have displayed your current vote count').html(msg);
       }
     }); 
    }
```

Comment: a lot of thanks Alpesh. its working but i want more specific. my msg variable is a array and i want to print it on different places. i tried JSON but it doesn't work.

Comment: @enthusiastic: as per your requirement you have tu use datataype as json in ajax, make your that you send the json encoded data from controller, and then you can loop through the returned json array in sucess function of ajax using jquery's `$.each` documented in this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/